# Editable to Non-Editable pdf using Aspose PDF

Tags: java, aspose.pdf

How can I save an editable pdf as Non-Editable after adding some text to it using Aspose PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding some text to a PDF file, you can set Document Privileges by using the code snippet below:

```
    //Open source document
    Document document = new Document(inputFile);        

    //Forbid all privileges on the document
    DocumentPrivilege privilege = DocumentPrivilege.getForbidAll();

    //Set the desired privileges
    PdfFileSecurity fileSecurity = new PdfFileSecurity(document);
    fileSecurity.setPrivilege(privilege);

    //Save resulting PDF document
    document.save(outputFile);
```

This will forbid all document privileges and the PDF file would not be editable anymore. I hope this will be helpful. Please let us know if you need any further assistance.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks! Worked fine. 
It&#39;s also working with doc.flatten().

Comment: With above approach, user could still unlock pdf for editing using external pdf tools like -smallpdf.com. Any other ways through which ASPOSE can make the file completely uneditable. One way I can think of is - convert each pdf page to image and then to pdf.